# Using Excel VBA to find last matching row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet that includes a date and an ActionCode column.  I'm using the Worksheet_Change event to run some code after the user enters an ActionCode.  I'd like to have a procedure that (when the user enters a specific code) will find the most recent previous instance of that code in the same column, then will return the date from that column.  For example:

```
Date     |ActionCode
11/4/1999| 2
12/5/1999| 3
1/2/2000 | 2
2/3/2001 | 5
3/1/2001 | 2
```

When the user enters the ActionCode "2" on 3/1/2001, I want the code to return `1/2/2000` rather than `11/4/1999`. I've looked at `MATCH`, but that seems like it would only return `11/4/1999`.  I've found a number of suggestions for doing this by entering formulas in a worksheet, but I can't figure out how to adapt them to VBA.

Comment: Are you interested in a (non-VBA) formula solution? From what you've posted, I don't see any reason to use VBA for this.

Comment: I've greatly simplified the example. The real thing would be too much of a mess with formula solutions.  Thanks for the suggestion below.  I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

**VBA solution:**

Here's a VBA solution using the Worksheet_Change event as you suggested. This will read user input from F1 and put output in F2. The data is assumed to be in columns A and B. To change these locations, you'll need to replace each instance of each with your desired input, output, and data addresses.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim userInput As Variant, codeTable() As Variant, maxDate As Long
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Make sure worksheet change affected user input cell
If Not Intersect(Range("F1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    userInput = Range("F1").Value
    If userInput = "" Then
        Range("F2") = ""
    Else
        'Store table data in an array for fast processing
        codeTable = Range("A2", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Value
        maxDate = 0
        'Find max date for input code
        For i = LBound(codeTable, 1) To UBound(codeTable, 1)
            If codeTable(i, 2) = userInput Then
                maxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(maxDate, codeTable(i, 1))
            End If
        Next i
        'Print output to sheet
        If maxDate = 0 Then
            Range("F2") = "No records"
        Else
            Range("F2") = Format(maxDate, "m/d/yyyy")
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Formula solution:**

You can achieve the same result with an array formula -- no need to add VBA to your workbook.

In your desired output cell, paste the following into the formula bar and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MAX(($B$2:$B$21=F1)*A2:A21)
```

In this formula, `B2:B21` hold your action codes, and `A2:A21` are the associated dates.

**Example output (both solutions):**

[image]

Comment: I like the array idea.  I definitely hadn't thought of that.  But the problem with using MAX is that it requires the date values to be unique.  I think there's the potential that users might need to enter multiple action codes with the same date in my application.  Maybe I could combine that with MAX(row number in range) to get the most recent date with the highest row number?

Comment: I think I found a solution here: http://www.get-digital-help.com/2014/02/07/find-last-matching-value-in-an-unsorted-list/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(Dates<J2)*(ActionCode=J3)*Dates,1)
```

- J2 = the User inputted Date, or `TODAY()` if you literally mean that.
- J3 = the User inputted Action Code

Because we are using the LARGE function against Dates that match the condition of being less than the user input, and also have an Action Code = the user input, the date entry order is irrelevant.

If the dates are sorted ascending, then you can use the simpler formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((Dates<J2)*(ActionCode=J3)),Dates)
```